# Call Editable after modal loads

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal call:

```
<a href='/urltoloadcontentfrom' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#driverprofile">View Driver Information</a>
```

The page displays the following url that needs to be editable

```
<a href="#" class="editable" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username" data-mode="inline">Link Here</a>
```

I need to bind "editable". I usually initialize editable with

```
$('.editable').editable();
```

I tried to initialize it with:

```
$('#driverprofile').on('shown', function () {
      $('.editable').editable(); 
    });
```

But this seem to fire before the content is displayed and its not initialized.

Any ideas?

"Editable" Library I'm using:
http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the following call when loading editable:

```
$('.modal-body').editable({selector: '.editable'});
```

This binds editable to .modal-body and that attaches itself to item with a class of .editable inside the modal-body regardless of when its generated.